# Can't figure out how to write interrupt handler for Z80 using SDCC

Tags: interrupt, z80, sdcc

I'm developing a program in C for the Z80 and compiling using SDCC.  I can't figure out how to create interrupt handlers for the NMI interrupt that starts at 0x0066 and the IM1 interrupt that starts at 0x0038.  I'm using these calls:

```
void IM1_InterruptHandler(void) __interrupt
```

and

```
void NMI_InterruptHandler (void) __critical __interrupt
```

and the resulting assembly looks about right but they aren't located at the proper addresses.  I did spot this thread:

https://sourceforge.net/p/sdcc/feature-requests/519/

but can't figure out how to use the above example crt0.s file with SDCC for a Z80 target.
Using the --use-crt switch doesn't seem to work.

```
unknown compiler option '--use-crt=crt0.s' ignored
```

Anyone experienced with Z80 development with SDCC that can provide some guidance?

Edit:
Still not quite there yet.  My crt.s file looks like this:

```
.module crt0
    .globl  _main
    .globl  _IM1_InterruptHandler
    .globl  _NMI_InterruptHandler

    .area   _HEADER (ABS)
    ;; Reset vector
    .org    0
    jp  init

    .org    0x08
    reti
    .org    0x10
    reti
    .org    0x18
    reti
    .org    0x20
    reti
    .org    0x28
    reti
    .org    0x30
    reti

    .org    0x38
    jp _IM1_InterruptHandler

    .org    0x66
    jp _NMI_InterruptHandler

    .org    0x100
init:
    ;; Stack at the top of memory.
    ld  sp,#0x8300

    call    _main


    ;; Ordering of segments for the linker.
    .area   _HOME
    .area   _CODE

    .area   _DATA

    .area   _CODE
```

And I'm doing the following:

```
sdasz80 -l -o mycrt.rel crt0.s
sdcc -mz80 --no-std-crt0 --code-loc 0x0000 --data-loc 0x8000 mycrt.rel ppclone_menu.c
```

Every thing seems to compile just fine but when I bring up the code in the disassembler I don't see any of the crt0 code being inserted above at locations  0x08 through 0x66.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a custom crt0 file you first need to compile it using `sdasz80`, which should be part of your SDCC install:

```
sdasz80 -o crt0_int.rel crt0_int.asm
```

Then you compile your program adding the following to the SDCC command line:

```
--no-std-crt0 crt0_int.rel
```

So the full command line would be something like:

```
sdcc --code-loc 0xWhatever --data-loc 0xWhatever -mz80 --no-std-crt0 crt0_int.rel somelibrary.lib yoursource.c
```

If you need examples of complete crt0 files, you have one in [my MSX software repository](https://github.com/Konamiman/MSX/tree/master/SRC/SDCC/crt0-msxdos).

**Edit:** You are passing `--code-loc 0x0000` to sdcc when compiling your source, this will cause the code section to overwrite whatever was defined in crt0. Change it to a more suitable value (for your crt0 looks like `0x0110` would be fine) or leave it out, so the compiler will choose an appropriate value by itself.

Comment: Updated question above due to stack overflow comment limits :(

Comment: Comments are not intended for posting long code samples. The proper way to provide more information is indeed to expand the question.